# I have some HTML that works in a way that seems like it would be impossible. How can this be explained?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have this HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 44%; display: inline;">
        <img width="95%" height="95%" style="border: none;" src="http://www.problemio.com/img/phoneimage.png">
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline; float: left; width:54%>">

    </div>
</div>

<p>
Some text blah blah
```

Note that there is nothing in the second div. And what this does is display the text that is below the second closing div in a space next to the image. In other words, it puts it in the space there the empty div is!

How can that be? Is this somehow a bug or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: The empty one has nothing in it so it takes up no space. The float:left puts the image at the left and the 'blah blah' goes in the next spot, which is next to it.

Comment: throw a `border:2px solid red;` and `border:2px solid blue;` around your 2 `div`s, and I think it will become clearer - basically your floats collapse, and the text moves up.

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys! So I guess this is the actual correct way to do this, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` is a `block`,
and you tried to use `display: inline` in a `block` is not right

try :

```
<div style="float: left; width: 44%; display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: I just tried the inline-block but it didn't seem to make any visible difference.  Which cases is it for?

Comment: I did not understand your comment, you want to know what caused the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing the floats so they will continue to float next to other content.  Apply a clear fix to the outermost div.  Adding `overflow: hidden` will work, but is antiquated.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/nNkJ8/

Comment: I actually did want the text and image to appear side by side.

Comment: @Genadinik so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do :-), but I see this:

- On your second div: width:54%>" it should be width:54%" (without the greater than symbol before the quotation mark)
- floats and display:inline do not get along together. I would replace both for a display:inline-block like this

  <div style="width: 44%; display: inline-block;">
- Even though your second div specifies a "width" attribute, if your div is empty, it will be rendered with a width of zero. Try adding a "background-color: red;" to your style to see what I say. You should see nothing.
- The text is next to your image because that's what float does. If you want to draw your text below the image you should "clear" your floats. Try this:

  <p style="clear:both;">
  Some text blah blah

If you decide to try the "display:inline-block" the "clear:both" is not necessary.